# How to use Usac Parameters in OpenCV for Fundamental Matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, parameters, ransac

first of all I'm new so sorry for any mistake.
im trying to compute a similarity score between two images based on the number of inliers in order to put the most similar one on top. I read about ransac method and I tried the one from `skimage` library. the problem Is that its too slow, almost 12 second for each query match (1 query and 25 image to be reranked for that query). So I read something new on OpenCV which use something called UsacParam which should be faster and more precise. The question is how do I use it? I tried to do this:

```
import cv2
_, inliers = cv2.findFundamentalMat(locations_1_to_use,locations_2_to_use,cv2.USAC_FAST)`
inliers = sum(np.ravel(inliers))`
```

but I have some problem with that `cv2.USAC_FAST` it tells me it doesn't exist but according to this link [link to evaluation of the usac methods](https://ducha-aiki.github.io/wide-baseline-stereo-blog/2021/05/17/OpenCV-New-RANSACs.html) they do. Anyone know more about this? how can I count the inliers?. The code I'm looking for should be in Python and maybe the sac library is available only in cpp? I only know that it is written in cpp

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? I checked with version 4.5.5 and it works without errors

Comment: I just did pip install opencv on google colab without specifying any version because I thought it would have download the last one… can it be the problem? moreover u did the exact same code as mine ?

Comment: There is no difference in the code. What is the error that you received? And what version of OpenCV do you have?

Comment: When I checked in Colab from my end, the default OpenCV version is `4.1.2`. To install the latest version execute `!pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64`. It might ask you to restart your runtime.

Comment: @JeruLuke thanks a lot I will check it as soon as possible and tell you more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this release](https://opencv.org/evaluating-opencvs-new-ransacs/) `cv2.USAC_FAST` was made available only in version 4.5.0 of OpenCV.

While cross checking its availability by toggling different versions [on this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) I can confirm the same.

As of [version 4.4.0](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) only the following three options are available:

- `cv2.LMEDS`
- `cv2.RANSAC`
- `cv2.RHO`

Additional options (all part of the USAC family) are available [from version 4.5.0](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) and above:

- `cv2.USAC_DEFAULT`
- `cv.USAC_PARALLEL`
- `cv2.USAC_FM_8PTS`
- `cv2.USAC_FAST`
- `cv2.USAC_ACCURATE`
- `cv2.USAC_PROSAC`
- `cv2.USAC_MAGSAC`

[image]

Comment: Okay I will check soon I’m out for now..  and let you know.. one last thing what about the findFundamentalMat method.. i saw someone using other models like estimateaffine2d or findHomography.. which is the best or how should I choose them based on my datasets

Comment: @Raffix These matrices are independent of datasets, rather their choice depends on what problem you want to solve. `cv2.findFundamentalMat` is used to understand epipolar geometry between images captured from 2 different cameras. The other two a related to projection matrices

Comment: Ok I got it.. my goal is to improve the recall score of an algorithm based on global descriptors for image retrieval.. I’m reranking the image that it returns with spatial verification.. i was just looking for faster than the skimage ransac function algorithm and I met this one. The goal is to improve robustness to viewpoint and illumination change. so do u think this method will work good or I need to switch to findHomography which is used also in other state of the art method like patchnetvlad ? Maybe it’s more indicated for the job

Comment: @Raffix To improve robustness to viewpoint and illumination changes you need good feature descriptors. You can opt for **RootSIFT**. To obtain faster matches during retrieval you can opt for **USAC**.

Comment: Yea yes I already have local descriptors. I extracted them with deep local feature extraction technics  .. I find the “most likely one” or maybe the most important one with a ckdTree model in order to “align” the similar descriptors and key point.. then I use that key point already “matched” with the ckdTree to count the number of inliers between query image and predicted image .. based on the number of inlier I reorder the list of predicted images.. that’s my workflow for now I think it’s ok right? I asked the question for that reason improve the matches speed during retrieval

Comment: @Raffix I guess you are on the right track

Comment: I’m really sorry to take your time but maybe u can help me.. what’s the difference in speed between flann marcher of opencv and ckdTree ? As far as I know the both do some kNN inside to align the local descriptors but maybe one is better than the other and I’m not optimizing that

Comment: I have not used `ckdTree` @Raffix